# Who's right about when to renew Let's Encrypt certificates?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, ssl-certificate-renewal

I received the following, sans unsubscribe link:

> Hello,
>
> Your certificate (or certificates) for the names listed below will expire in 1 days (on 14 Aug 16 23:07 +0000). Please make sure to renew your certificate before then, or visitors to your website will encounter errors.
>
> unixtalk.chat
>   www.unixtalk.chat
>
> For any questions or support, please visit https://community.letsencrypt.org/. Unfortunately, we can't provide support by email.
>
> If you are receiving this email in error, unsubscribe at **[DELETED]** (HTTP link, we know. We're working on it!)
>
> Regards,
>   The Let's Encrypt Team

I don't remember exactly when I registered the certificate, but the domain was created 2016-02-10.

When I ran the following command:

```
letsencrypt/letsencrypt-auto -d unixtalk.chat
```

it allowed me to create a certificate, but warned me that I was updating the certificate well before it needed to be renewed, and somewhere in there I think it advised me that such early certificate renewals would be throttled.

So...

When should I be renewing certificates obtained through Let's Encrypt?

Thanks,

Comment: Renew it when `certbot renew` decides to renew it.

Comment: You can see when a certificate expires by looking at the notAfter value **in the certificate**; depending on the tool or interface you use this is often labelled Expires or [Valid] To or [Valid] Until.

Answer (score 0):

Certificates from letsencrypt are publically auditable

- [unixtalk.chat](https://crt.sh/?q=unixtalk.chat)
- [www.unixtalk.chat](https://crt.sh/?q=unixtalk.chat)

The rate limits are described [here](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/rate-limits/).

> When should I be renewing certificates obtained through Let's Encrypt?

You should renew the certificate before it expires. Personally I run a cron job a couple of times a week and renew it at the earliest opportunity that doesn't require it to be forced.

Comment: 30 days is what I remember,  citation needed.   they also request crons run at a random offset.